# Selected Index Changed in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown `Grade` with values

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

On selection change of dropdown, the values of `Student` dropdown should be loaded.

```
when "a" is selected, Dropdown students should populate ["Anna", "Hannah"]
When "b" is selected, Dropdown students should populate ["Billy", "Cathy"]
When "c" is selected, Dropdown students should populate ["Albert", "Deepti"]
```

Can we keep all the grades and students in single array(in js file)? If yes, how can I load only those values on selected index changed in javascript from the array ?

To add to the description, my code is in HTML, so my controls are:

```
 <select id="grade" name="grade"></select>
 <select id="student" name="student"></select>
```

Modified :

```
    var grades_rank;
    var grades_student;
    var grades = {     "very good": ["Anna", "Hannah"],     "good":
 ["Billy", "Cathy"],     "above average": ["Albert", "Deepti"] }  ;
```

To load the dropdown:

```
for (var _i = 0; _i < grades.length; _i++) {
            jQ('#Stu_Grades').append(jQ("<option></option>").attr("value", _i).text(grades[_i][grades_rank]));
        }
```

Comment: I added in the description. Will add more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an object:

```
var grades = {
    a: ["Anna", "Hannah"],
    b: ["Billy", "Cathy"],
    c: ["Albert", "Deepti"]
}
```

When the dropdown value changes, use its new value to lookup the names you want to use:

```
grades[a]; // ["Anna", "Hannah"]
grades[b]; // ["Billy", "Cathy"]
```

When all is said and done, it might look something like the following:

```
// Lookup chart for grades and students
var grades = {
    a: ["Anna", "Hannah"],
    b: ["Billy", "Cathy"],
    c: ["Albert", "Deepti"]
}

// Reference our dropdown lists
var grade = document.getElementById("grade");
var student = document.getElementById("student");

// Add an event handler to the 'change' event on our grades
grade.addEventListener("change", function(){
    // A few variables we'll use
    var option, g, c, i;
    // Clear student list
    while ( c = student.firstChild ) student.removeChild( c );
    // If the new value is a grade in our lookup
    if ( g = grades[ this.value ] ) {
        // Populate student list
        for ( i = 0; i < g.length; i++ ) {
            option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = g[i];
            student.appendChild(option);
        }
    }
}, false);​
```

Comment: hi, i tried the code and have added under modified section.  
Here grades.length value is coming as undefined, but grades is picking up correct value from array(checked using add watch). How do I fill up first dropdown in this case ?

Comment: @RMN `grades` is an object and does not have a `length` property. To iterate it, use `for (grade in grades) {}` if that's what you're looking to do. If you use that `for` loop, `grade` will hold the key (something like "a", "b", or "c") and then `grades[grade]` will hold the value (like the arrays)

Answer (score 1):

If you really *really* want just one array, you can keep them all in an array of objects

```
var studentsByGrade = [ 
    { "grade": "a", "name": "Anna" }, 
    { "grade": "a", "name": "Hannah" }, 
    { "grade": "b", "name": "Billy" }, 
    { "grade": "b", "name": "Cathy" }, 
    { "grade": "c", "name": "Albert" }, 
    { "grade": "c", "name": "Deepti" }
];
```

use this to populate the #grade dropdown:

```
for (var i=0;i<studentsByGrade.length;i++) {
    if ($("#grade option[value='+"studentsByGrade[i].grade"+']").length === 0) {
        $("#grade").append("<option value='"+studentsByGrade[i].grade+'>"+studentsByGrade[i].grade+"</option>");
    }
}
```

and put this as a change handler on the #grade dropdown:

```
$("#grade").on('change', function() {
    var grade = this.value;        
    students.innerHTML = "";
    for (var i=0;i<studentsByGrade.length;i++) {
        if (studentsByGrade[i].grade == grade) {
            $("#student").append("<option value='"+studentsByGrade[i].name+'>"+studentsByGrade[i].name+"</option>");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I like the array of objects, but wouldn't it make sense to use the setup like @JonathanSampson? Obviously, if they need to store more than just a list of names, they could still do `var grades = {a: {"names": [], "other": "stuff"}, b: {"names": [], "other": "whatever"}, etc.};`

Comment: Maybe, but RMN asked for a _single_ array ;)

Comment: True, but who knows if that's required. You're right though, you answered as the question specified, but the question may not always have the best design. Again, your answer is perfectly fine :) Just wanted to point it out

Comment: I concur, it's better to give the answer that is needed rather than the answer that is deserved.